# Java Sorting for lowest fare in selenium

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, selenium, webdriver

I am automating makemytrip.com using selenium, i want to find the lowest fare among the list.
here is my code

```
List<WebElement> results = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'clearfix listing_row')]"));
System.out.println(results.size());

for (WebElement result : results) 
{
     WebElement price = result.findElement(By.xpath("./div/div"));
     WebElement name = result.findElement(By.xpath(".//p[contains(@class,'price_info')]"));
     System.out.println(name.getText()+" : "+price.getText());
}
```

Comment: Which type of list it returning to you?

Comment: you can use comparator and sort in your own way..

Answer (score 0):

put all `price.getText()` in `java.util.List` then use `java.util.Collections.min(list)` list is your list, it will find minimum fare.

Comment: no its not working. i want to display lowest fare among list.

Comment: Can you post your list code? and output of your code?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that will be to:

**1- Sort the list by 'Price' in ascending order.**

**2-Then, get the price value of the first flight.**

The Below code will work for you:

```
//Click on the Price column header to sort the list by Price.
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'price_informtn')]/a")).click();

//Check if the sorting is by ascending by checking if the arrow is 'up'; if not click on it to sort by ascending
String arrow_direction = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'price_informtn')]//span")).getAttribute("class");
if(!arrow_direction.contains("up"))
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'price_informtn')]/a")).click();

Thread.sleep(2000);//Sleeping 2 seconds to avoid the StaleElementReferenceException

//Now retrieve the price of the First flight, as it is the lowest fare
String lowest_fare = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'clearfix listing_row')][1]//div[contains(@class,'listing_top clearfix')]/div[7]/p[1])).getText();
System.out.println("\nLowest fare is: "+ lowest_fare);
```